# TableViewCell, dynamically show Media Player controls iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am currently developing a app which records some audio files. The audio files are stored locally and the path is stored in core data.

I am populating a TableView with the list of Audio's recorded. 
When I click a tableviewcell, I am able to play the recorded voice.

I want to show some controls on the table view (like play and pause button same as voice recorder app in iPhone) which will be shown only when the user selects the table cell and will be disappeared when he selects other cell.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement UITableViewCell you'll be able to custom the cell to your own liking.
You can also use the method 
     setSelected:( BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
to change the cell depending on wether it is (or isn't) selected.

Answer (score 0):

Write the code to create a custom `UITableViewCell`(dynamically). You will not get the issue.

Try to use following sample code;

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];
}
UIImageView *cellImageView1=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,80)];
UIImage *cellImage1=[UIImage imageNamed:@"table_bar.png"];
cellImageView1.image=cellImage1;
cell.backgroundView=cellImageView1;
NSString *projectName = [projectNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.imageView.image=[self returnImage:projectName];
cell.imageView.frame=CGRectMake(10, 05, 40, 40);
cell.imageView.image=[self returnImage:projectName];
UILabel *cellLabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 15, 150, 30)];
cellLabel.text=projectName;
cellLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
cellLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
cellLabel.tag = 4444;
[cell.contentView addSubview:cellLabel];
[cellLabel release];
cell.accessoryView =(UIButton*) [buttonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
```

I hope it will help you.